# APIView pagination - DRF

Tags: python, pagination, django-rest-framework

I have a problem creating paging using APIView of DRF. I've seen in some places that paging with APIView is not so trivial, the code below was made from some results in my search, however, I'm still in trouble. One of them, is that I do not know how to pass a minimum number of results per request. Another is that the page number does not appear or if there is a next page after it.

```
class MerchantOrders(APIView):

authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def get(self, request, pk):

    orders = Order.objects.filter(merchant_id=pk)

    paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()

    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(orders, request)

    response = ListOrderSerializer(result_page, many=True)
    return Response(response.data)
```

and this is an example of a return

```
[
{
    "product": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Blusa #889",
        "barcode": "8880",
        "description": "Maecenas vestibulum imperdiet dapibus. Proin semper tortor lectus, nec lacinia felis fringilla et."
    },
    "price": "16.00",
    "is_ative": true
},
{
    "product": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Blusa #915",
        "barcode": "4238",
        "description": "Donec euismod pulvinar condimentum."
    },
    "price": "12.00",
    "is_ative": true
}
```

]

I have no idea if this is something normal because I have used LimitOffsetPagination or if I am doing it wrong. I ask that if you have a better solution for paging using APIView, feel free to share with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django REST framework source code is your friend there.
In your case, you are missing some parts as you can see from the [list implementation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/2b6245db5359571f10d27ace16473d70e160dce2/rest_framework/mixins.py#L39-L48):

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```